# Canvas.ApplicationContext setCanvasUrlPath not respecting escaped ampersand

Tags: apex, canvas

I am trying to set my canvas URL Path to a URL with an escaped ampersand contained in one of the query string parameters, and for some reason it clears the rest of the value for that parameter.

For example, if I call:

```
Canvas.ApplicationContext.setCanvasUrlPath('/?reportid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&filter=UK%26I&height=2950&width=915');
```

And look at the network traffic in the browser, the canvas URL will be called:

http://www.example.com/?reportid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&filter=UK&height=2950&width=915

Notice that the '%26I' is removed from the filter parameter.

If I put debug statements in the application, I can see that the URL I'm setting is correct, and if I call:

```
System.debug('---canvasURL: ' + Canvas.ApplicationContext.getCanvasUrl());
```

It logs the correct URL.  Same problem in Chrome and IE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try encoding the URL string before passing it to the setter there?

Comment: %26 is the encoding of '&'

Comment: What did you end up doing? :-/

Comment: @Krishnan This is a while ago, but I think I had to replace the '&' to another character string (like |||) and set that as the CanvasUrlPath, and on the consumption, convert any instances of that other character string back to &

Comment: hmm ok thanks. I ended up `EncodingUtil.urlEncode(myUrl)` before setting it to `app.setCanvasUrlPath(encodedMyUrl)`.